# Windows phone 8 design consideration

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am creating an app where I want to display the rectangles which display image at the background and an overlay where I can display some text on top of that image. See the attached image (mock up)

[image]

So what would be the easiest approach to achieve the desired layout?

1. Canvas
2. Rectangle with imagestroke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did that one day with something like that:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Image Grid.Rowspan="2">
<Textblock Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignement="Bottom"/>
</grid>
```

With that code the text should be at the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Grid` and put an `Image` and `TextBlock` in it.